# How to get the underlying object bound to a control?

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, bindingsource

Using WinForms and data bindings.

I have a form containing a BindingSource component and I have set the DataSource property from the designer to a class:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyString {get;set;}
}
```

Now, how do I get the MyClass object assigned to the BindingSource from source code?

I've tried casting the DataSource property of the BindingSource to MyClass, not working.

### Additional notes

My problem seems to be that I set the DataSource from the WinForms Designer.
The DataSource is then set to the type MyClass and not an actual object.

So, is there an object created that I can access and modify from code so that values from the bounded object shows on the form's controls ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an object data source in a WinForms application, from the menu choose `Data > Add New Data Source`. In the Data Source Configuration Wizard choose `Object` and click `Next`. Select the class you wish to use as a data source and click `Finish`. The public properties of the class should now appear in the Data Sources window.

Then after you do that create an instance of the class and assign it to the `DataSource` property. For example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass()
    {
        MyString = "aaaa"
    };

    myClassBindingSource.DataSource = myClass;
}
```

Comment: From what I understand I could bind to a simple class.

Comment: Yes, you can bind certain controls to a class. Please read the following article for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8aebh9k.aspx

Comment: Follow-up on your update: It's already wired in this way. The problem is that the DataSource property is set to the type of the object but not an actual object.

Comment: I finally think I understood your question completely. I've updated the answer again.

Comment: @Stécy - there's no way how to do that. But what's wrong with filling it from code. Is there any particular reason why you want to do that.

Comment: There's one simple reason: to provide an environment where a "programmer" would only drag/drop components and controls on the design surface and setup properties.